# Setting of the "Sky Doll" graphic novel series

Tags: sky-doll

[*Sky Doll*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_Doll) is an enchantingly painted Italian graphic novel series [published by Soleil](http://skydoll.lesite.free.fr/) and later translated into English by Marvel Worldwide. While I love the visual, almost hand-painted impact this series has, I am rather confused about the setting of the entire series.

The central conflict, about two goddesses [Agape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agape) (representing spiritual love) and Lodovica (representing sexual love) is endlessly fascinating. However the protagonist Sky Doll's story works on the planet Aqua although there are references to the galaxy, etc.

I just don't get *where* most of the story is occurring ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [descriptions in French](http://skydoll.lesite.free.fr/skydoll_V1/?page_id=1107) (I haven't read the books):

The story takes place in a fictional locale. The first volume, *The Yellow City*, opens on the planet [Papathéa](https://www.comicvine.com/papathea/34-55676/) where Joanna, the Yellow City, is located. The second volume narrates Noa's visit to the planet Aqua. The third volume comes back to Papathéa.

I'm not sure this is what you're after. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up somewhat. Thank you. My confusion was more about how architectural/aesthetic styles of each story was wildly different - making every panel a multiverse. I'll refresh the books again.